# slideshow timing does not work properly joomla

Tags: joomla

i have a web site to fix http://www.clickconsultingservices.com , when the page loads there is a top slideshow showing banners, but when the page loads the very first banner is shown only for an instant and then goes to the next one. What is wrong with it, and how can i make it to take as much time as all the other banners? i feel like its a problem with page load, that by the time page loads the time of the first banner already expires. I tried changing the timing but it did not give effect to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that it loads all the frames of your animation, then starts the animation on page load.  The judder is simply the bit before the animation starts, and all the frames are visible.  You briefly see the last frame, rather than the first one.

Try adding visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; to all the slider divs, apart from the first one.

```
<div class="slide" style="width: 928px; position: absolute;visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;">
```

(Note that it's better coding not to use inline styles, but that seems the simplest way here, and you are already using some on that div)

Also: confusion may be caused by the image names which do not seem to match what they actually are, eg 2clickconsultingslider_email.jpg is about print, not email.

Comment: hi, thanx for yuor reply but the problem was not solved, if i do as u say then sliders just would start much later after page load, and still have the same problem. however i noticed one thing - it works properly on Mozila but all other browsers having the problem. does this tell you something by any chance?